# Defining join criteria between targets and transactions as a set of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a problem I am currently solving with a very messy solution, I would like to know if there is an easier way to maintain this.

The solution I have requires a new column to be added to two views and several reports every time what people are targeted on (often).

I have a view returning sale transactions with several attributes (heavily cropped as view has 100+ columns):

```
SalesPerson   SaleType   StockType   Date         Value
------------------------------------------------------------
James         Type A     Type B      2013-01-01   100
James         Type B     Type C      2013-01-02   200
James         Type C     Type C      2013-01-03   100
James         Type A     Type A      2013-01-04   300
James         Type B     Type B      2013-01-05   100
James         Type C     Type B      2013-01-06  -100
Harry         Type A     Type B      2013-01-01   200
Harry         Type B     Type C      2013-01-02   200
Harry         Type C     Type C      2013-01-03    50
Harry         Type A     Type A      2013-01-04    50
Harry         Type B     Type B      2013-01-05   100
Harry         Type C     Type B      2013-01-06  -200
```

I then have a table with targets like:

```
SalesPerson   Year    Month   TargetType  Value
---------------------------------------------------
James         2013    1       1           500
James         2013    1       2           400
Harry         2013    1       2           300
Harry         2013    1       3           150
```

To connect the two I translate the sales table with a view that includes if the sale line is included in each type:

```
CREATE VIEW SalesWithTargets

AS

SELECT SalesPerson
     , Date
     , Value
     , CASE WHEN SaleType  = 'Type A'
            AND  Stocktype = 'Type B'
       THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Type1]

     , CASE WHEN SaleType  = 'Type B'
            AND  Stocktype IN ('Type B', 'Type C')
       THEN 2 ELSE 0 END AS [Type2]

     , CASE WHEN SaleType  IN ('Type A', 'Type C')
            AND  Stocktype NOT IN ('Type B', 'Type C')
       THEN 3 ELSE 0 END AS [Type3]

FROM SalesTransactions
```

Then to check against the targets I join the Target table to the new `SalesWithTargets` view as below:

```
SELECT SalesPerson
     , TargetType
     , Year
     , Month
     , Value AS Target 
     , SUM(Value) AS Actual

FROM Targets
LEFT JOIN SalesWithTargets ON Targets.TargetType = SalesWithTargets.[Type1]
                           OR Targets.TargetType = SalesWithTargets.[Type2]
                           OR Targets.TargetType = SalesWithTargets.[Type3]
```

I now have 23 separate types so have 23 case statements running for every row in the transactions table, performance is getting to be a problem.

I have tried to create a stored procedure to run this using `COALESCE` or `ISNULL` but I can't find a way to allow a list of items.

Is there a way this can be done to allow me to define target types outside a case statement? eg:

```
TType   SaleTypeCriteria  SaleTypeVal       StockTypeCriteria StockTypeVal
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       Equal             Type A            Equal             Type B
2       Equal             Type B            In                Type B, Type C
3       In                Type A, Type C    Not In            Type A, Type C
```

Comment: Running a or statement 23 times will be very slow :) and you want the first one i assume? What is the problem with coalesce? You have to write the 23 left join then coalesce with the 23 values and a last one in case everything is null

Comment: @MatheseF The problem with `COALESCE` is allowing `IN` and `NOT IN`. I don't quite understand what you mean by 23 left joins can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SalesPerson
     , TargetType
     , Year
     , Month
     , Value AS Target 
     , SUM(coalesce(a1.Value, a2.value, a3.value, 0) AS Actual

FROM Targets
LEFT JOIN SalesWithTargets a1 ON Targets.TargetType = SalesWithTargets.[Type1]
LEFT JOIN SalesWithTargets a1 ON Targets.TargetType = SalesWithTargets.[Type2]
LEFT JOIN SalesWithTargets a1 ON Targets.TargetType = SalesWithTargets.[Type3]
```

This 23 times, i assumed value is coming from the left joined table

Comment: This is just re factoring what I have currently, while performance might increase slightly, it doesn't solve the problem of adding a new column for every used permutation of targets.

Comment: of course it's refactoring :) you could have sql dynamic to generate the left join if you think the number of join will growth and don't want to forget to update the query :) But this is often and should be faster than writing or

Comment: I have tested this on the test data I have and performance is drastically worse. I think it is because it must process all case statements every time the `SalesWithTargets` view is joined to the `Targets` table.